# How do I make my layout fill the screen when I rotate it?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have one problem with my code and I could use some help. I made an app that tracks the statistics of a football game.The app works fine the problem is when I rotate my phone screen which is when 2 problems appear:
The layout doesn´t match the screen width, making the text and buttons overlap one another and when I turn the phone around, for some reason, the scores reset. I have a reset button but I don´t know why it activates when I rotate the screen. Would appreciate some help. Thanks for reading!
Here´s the code in XML and Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int golosA = 0;
int faltasA = 0;
int forasDeJogoA = 0;
int cartoesAmarelosA = 0;
int expulsoesA = 0;
int golosB = 0;
int faltasB = 0;
int forasDeJogoB = 0;
int cartoesAmarelosB = 0;
int expulsoesB = 0;
int cantosA = 0 ;
int cantosB = 0 ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void resetScore(View v) {
    golosA=0;
    faltasA=0;
    expulsoesA=0;
    cartoesAmarelosA = 0;
    forasDeJogoA = 0 ;
    golosB=0;
    faltasB=0;
    expulsoesB=0;
    cartoesAmarelosB = 0;
    forasDeJogoB = 0 ;
    cantosA = 0 ;
    cantosB = 0 ;

    displayFaltasEquipaA(0);
    displayGolosButtonA(0);
    displayExpulsoes(0);
    displayCartoesA(0);
    displayForasJogoA(0);
    displayCartoesB(0);
    displayExpulsoesB(0);
    displayForasJogoB(0);
    displayGolosButtonB(0);
    displayFaltasEquipaB(0);
    displayCantosA(0);
    displayCantosB(0);
}

public void displayGolosButtonA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.golos_equipa_a);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void golosTeamA(View view) {
    golosA = golosA + 1;
    displayGolosButtonA(golosA);
}

public void displayFaltasEquipaA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faltas_equipa_a);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void faltasTeamA(View view) {
    faltasA = faltasA + 1;
    displayFaltasEquipaA(faltasA);
}
public void displayCantosA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cantos_teamA);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void cantosA(View view) {
  cantosA  = cantosA + 1;
    displayCantosA(cantosA);
}
public void displayCantosB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cantos_teamB);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void cantosB(View view) {
    cantosB  = cantosB + 1;
    displayCantosB(cantosB);
}

public void displayForasJogoA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foras_equipa_a);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void forasEquipaA(View view) {
    forasDeJogoA = forasDeJogoA + 1;
    displayForasJogoA(forasDeJogoA + 1);
}

public void displayCartoesA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_amarelos_a);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void amarelosTeamA(View view) {
    cartoesAmarelosA = cartoesAmarelosA + 1;
    displayCartoesA(cartoesAmarelosA);
}

public void displayExpulsoes(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expulsoes_a);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void expulsoesTeamA(View view) {
    expulsoesA = expulsoesA + 1;
    displayExpulsoes(expulsoesA);
}

public void displayGolosButtonB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.golos_equipa_b);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void golosTeamB(View view) {
    golosB = golosB + 1;
    displayGolosButtonB(golosB);
}

public void displayFaltasEquipaB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faltas_equipa_b);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void faltasTeamB(View view) {
    faltasB = faltasB + 1;
    displayFaltasEquipaB(faltasB);
}

public void displayForasJogoB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foras_equipa_b);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void forasJogoB(View view) {
    forasDeJogoB = forasDeJogoB + 1;
    displayForasJogoB(forasDeJogoB + 1);
}

public void displayCartoesB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_amarelos_b);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void amarelosTeamB(View view) {
    cartoesAmarelosB = cartoesAmarelosB + 1;
    displayCartoesB(cartoesAmarelosB);
}

public void displayExpulsoesB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expulsoes_b);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void expulsoesB(View v) {
    expulsoesB = expulsoesB + 1;
    displayExpulsoesB(expulsoesB);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the score resetting problem, try adding the line :

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

into your manifest file.  It tells your activity to not react to screen orientation changes.  It will still rotate, but will prevent the variables to resets.

For the rotation problem, have you tried editing the rotated version of you app ?  I don't know which editor you're using, but in Android Studio, in the Design page, you got the option to create the landscape version and changes his design manually.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the line helped with the reset problem. I´ll try to use the design tab to edit the landscape.Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% positive but my gut tells me You need to add an onOrientationChanged listener and have it set text to same values again when in horizontal/landscape mode.

It has to do with the activity lifecycle and when the orientation changes it temporarily stops/pauses (not sure which) the activity if you don’t save those values or set the values then they are set to the default value which looks like 0 in your code.